# AForge Camera Memory Leak in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, aforge

Before you mark this thread as a duplicate, please consider that I have been attempting to debug the following code for a few days already, and still cannot seem to find a solution.

I'm working on a camera class that has one public method: to return the current frame. In the background, it keeps updating the current frame every time a new frame event occurs (please see code below).

Through commenting code out, I have come to the conclusion that a leak is happening here: `this.currentFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();`. Moreover, I have conducted a few memory performance diagnostics in Visual Studio, and it seems the the `this.currentFrame` object keeps growing in size (seems to behave similarly to a linked list).

I guess my question is why is `this.currentFrame` growing? I am using the `Image.Clone()` method so nothing else should be referring to the memory space that it is referring to. In addition, before I update it and I make it refer to `null` just in case. So why is it not being garbage collected when the `this.currentFrame` pointer points to a new memory location?

I doubt there is a bug in the AForge code... I know it's probably something small in my code, but I can't see it...

```
public WebCamClass(VideoCaptureDevice camera)
{
    this.cam = camera;
    this.currentFrame = new Bitmap(Project.Properties.Resources.defaultImage);
    this.cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
    this.cam.Start();
}

private VideoCaptureDevice cam;
private Bitmap currentFrame;

private void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    this.currentFrame = null;
    this.currentFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
}

public Image saveFrame()
{
    return this.currentFrame;
}
```

I have also tried this with no success:

```
public Image saveFrame()
{
    return (Bitmap)this.currentFrame.Clone();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you just need to use "using", it automatically dispose the bitmap object.

```
private void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
       using(Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
       {
          //your code using bmp object
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the using in a windows forms app the app crashed drawing the screen with a null reference error, in the en I declared Bitmap bmp as a global variable and then on `cam_NewFrame` put

```
if (bmp != null) bmp.Dispose();
```

this fixed the memory leak